# Reading Email Message Body

Tags: vb.net, email, message, email-client

I having some problem trying to understand how to read the body of email messages. I hope there's someone here whom have done it and can help me.

I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2019 and have a web form to read my `gmail` account.
[image]

The behind code for the button "Get Emails" is as follows:

```
    Dim client As OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client = New OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client()

    client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, True)
    client.Authenticate("daniel@gmail.com", "W-12345")

    Dim messageCount As Integer = client.GetMessageCount()
    Dim text1 As String = ""
    Dim allMessages As List(Of OpenPop.Mime.Message) = New List(Of OpenPop.Mime.Message)

    For count As Integer = 1 To messageCount
        Try
            allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(count))
            text1 = client.GetMessageHeaders(count).Subject & "( " & client.GetMessageUid(count).Trim & " )"
            ListBox1.Items.Add(text1)
        Catch ex As OpenPop.Pop3.Exceptions.PopServerException
            allMessages.Add(Nothing)
        End Try
    Next
    ListBox1.DataBind()
```

I managed to read it and display the Message header and its ID.
How do I code to display the message body instead.
I have problem on how to use the Messagepart class to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim client As New OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client()

    client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, True)
    client.Authenticate("your-mail@gmail.com", "mail-password")

    Dim messageCount As Integer = client.GetMessageCount()
    Dim allMessages As New List(Of OpenPop.Mime.Message)

    For i As Integer = 1 To messageCount
        MsgBox(client.GetMessage(i).ToMailMessage.Body)
    Next
```